# Checking surface area of com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon

Tags: polygon, area, jts-topology-suite

I would like to compare the area of a polygon created with some coordinates passed and ensure that it is less than half the sky or a set area.
My approach to create the Polygon is as follow:

```
Geometry geometry =
                (new GeometryFactory()).createPolygon(coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[coordinates.size()]));
```

I need to check the area of the geometry object above and ensure that it is less than a certain area.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: did you try (and reject for some reason) `geometry.getArea()` - https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html#getArea--

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I was able to use geometry.getArea() but am unsure on how I can compare this to the area of a sky. For example. I want to ensure that this area is less than half the area of the sky visible from a point on the earth

Comment: that doesn't really make sense - you are trying to compare 2 completely different things there. Please [edit] your question with to make it clearer and add more of you relevant code

Answer (score 2):

A JTS `Polygon` has a [`getArea()`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html#getArea--) method which will return its area as floating point number.

```
double area = geometry.getArea();
if (area >= 1000) {
    System.out.println("Area is >= 1000 areal units");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bugmenot. How can I compare this area to a area of a sky as seen from a certain point on earth ?

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean. Is the polygon also over your head? At what height? Perhaps you could draw a sketch.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a completely different question. I'd suggest you post it with an appropriate title and very elaborate description (e.g. if you are standing on an empty sphere, ellipsoid or geoid or if there are mountains and buildings to be involved in it).